# Trouble using the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint connector in Flow/PowerAutomate = Invalid slug header for BLOBs

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow

I’m getting the dreaded "Invalid slug header for BLOBs" error message

"message": "Invalid slug header for BLOBs. Slug headers must be server- or web-relative URL of the file. Server-relative URLs begins with a forward slash (\"/\").\r\nclientRequestId: fea67666-7382-44a7-a185-3c20d91b57b2\r\nserviceRequestId: cca7409f-7080-2000-42e3-84a196d20638",

"status": 400,

"source": "https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/DatblyguAcAdeiladuOrNewydd-DevelopmentandNewBuild/_vti_bin/listd...",

"errors": []

I’ve called the listdata.svc using the Flow inputed doclib name and it works as expected in a browser

I’ve verified the document set unique ID (I’ve even tried to create a standard folder using the correct ID = same result)

Here’s the connector as setup = I'm trying to create a Document Set named 'Test' (using the verified document set ID listed) in the Project Documents doclib in the DatblyguAcAdeiladuOrNewydd-DevelopmentandNewBuild Teams Site Collection

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [this](https://sharepointycl.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/creating-sharepoint-online-document-set-in-microsoft-flow/), [this](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/microsoft-flow-create-a-document-set/) or [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-create-document-set-using-Microsoft-Flow/td-p/276044) and see if you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, we don't have access to the premium http connector or I would have checked it out :-( Those other links were the basis to what I've been trying ! (sorry, I should have mentioned them). Can you see anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: The error tells you want is wrong, your slug needs to be server-relative, remove the `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com` from the slug so that it begins with`/sites/`

Comment: Hi Willman, have tried this in the past by working the problem, but tried again just now by changing Slug in the connector to = 
/sites/DatblyguAcAdeiladuOrNewydd-DevelopmentandNewBuild/Project Documents/Test|0x0120D52000E50F36049A828E488C1ED1D3067F621E00767AFA6CBF465142B481E61D6A216973

Get exactly the same error message?

Comment: Just a nudge to keep this current - can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Another Nudge? Please someone, help us!